# Como ver objeto em c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Olá, como posso ver meu objeto em c#, como o `var_dump()` em `php`, um exemplo, para mostrar as infos dos objetos, segue meu código:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "IdFuncionario,Nome,IdDepartamento")] Funcionario funcionario)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Funcionarios.Add(funcionario);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(funcionario);
    }
```

no caso, precisava ver o objeto `funcionario` obrigado.

Comment: Você pode usar o `breakpoint`.

Comment: @FilipeOliveira como?

Comment: No Visual Studio, você pode clicar do lado esquerdo da tela, atrás dos números e aparecerá uma bola vermelha. Quando a execução chegar nesse ponto, irá parar e você pode passar o mouse em cima do objeto e explorar ele.

Comment: booa, consegui aki @FilipeOliveira, estou com um problema no model, vou fazer uma pergunta nova e ve la

Comment: @FilipeOliveira olha a pergunta que fiz, ve se pode me ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99048/erro-ao-criar-dados-com-chave-estrangeira-c-visual-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o breakpoint do Visual Studio e ver o estado do seu objeto.

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]