# Erro ao criar dados com chave estrangeira

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Olá, não estou conseguindo inserir dados em uma tabela que tem chave estrangeira, segue meu model:

[image: Model]

2 tabelas, `Departamento` e `Funcionario`, o funcionário tem a chave estrangeira `IdDepartamento`.

Ae gerei os `controllers` tudo certinho, eu consigo adicionar um departamento sem problemas, mas quando vou adicionar um funcionário, ele da erro, tela de cadastrar funcionario com o `dropdown` dos departamentos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ae quando coloco um nome e o id do departamento ja criado, da o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o  `controller` do funcionario:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "IdFuncionario,Nome,IdDepartamento")] Funcionario funcionario)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Funcionarios.Add(funcionario);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(funcionario);
    }
```

`Funcionarios Create Controller` para gerar a `ViewBag`:

```
    // GET: Funcionarios/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.IdDepartamento = new SelectList(db.Departamentos, "IdDepartamento", "Nome");
        return View();
    }
```

View `Create` do Funcionario:
    @model MVC4.Models.Funcionario

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 

{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Funcionario</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IdDepartamento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdDepartamento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.DropDownList("IdDepartamento", ViewBag.IdDepartamento as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Obrigado

**RESOLVIDO**

Pessoal, obrigado a todos que me ajudaram, consegui resolver usando o seguinte código no `FuncionariosController`:

```
             var dp = db.Departamentos.Find(Convert.ToInt32(funcionario.IdDepartamento));
            if (dp == null)
            {
                dp = new Departamento();
            }
            funcionario.Departamento = dp;
```

Ou seja, ele da um `find` em departamentos pra ver se encontra com o IdDepartamento passado, se for == null, dp recebe a classe Departamento.

Comment: O erro descrito não tem nada a ver com erro na chave estrangeira, é justamente o oposto, a chave estrangeira esta gerando o erro por que ela esta funcionando, e avisando que na tabela departamento não tem nada. O idDepartamento = 1, não existe.

Comment: Precisamos também do código da sua *View*.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez vou postar a View do create

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez tem dados da tabela Departamentos

Comment: Concordo com o @ChristianBeregula, este erro ocorre porque a sua tabela funcionário esta fazendo referência para um tabela que não te o registro esperado. Erro muito comum... Pode ser simulado no SQL.
O ideial é que esse campo "IdDepartamento", seja uma combobox com a lista dos departamentos (Cadastre os departamentos antes do funcionario), que irá funcionar bem.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez fiz umas alterações na pergunta, de uma olhada por favor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isto aqui não está bom:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IdDepartamento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Sendo uma chave estrangeira, você pode preenchê-la usando um recurso no *Controller*. Minha sugestão é:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdDepartamento, ((IEnumerable<Departamento>)ViewBag.Departamentos).Select(option => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = option.Nome,
    Value = option.IdDepartamento.ToString(),
    Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.IdDepartamento== option.IdDepartamento)
}), "Selecione...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Este `ViewBag.Departamentos` você pode preencher na *Action* `GET` de `Create` da seguinte forma:

```
ViewBag.Departamentos = db.Departamentos;
```

Comment: fiz umas alterações na pergunta, de uma olhada por favor

Comment: quando coloco seu código na view, ele da erro no " (IEnumerable<Departamento>) "  segue o erro: " The type or namespace 'Departamento' could not be found"

Comment: Colocou no começo da *View* `@using MeuProjeto.Models`?

Comment: coloquei assim no meu Create do Funcionario: " MeuProjeto.Models.Funcionario "

Comment: Assim como? Não consigo ler sua tela. Atualize sua pergunta com a tentativa completa pra que eu possa te ajudar.

Comment: ta, vou colocar minha view completa do Create do funcionarios, so um min

Comment: Atualizado @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Comment: @Furlan Você não está sequer seguindo o que eu coloquei na minha resposta. Não sei se vale a pena continuar com isso.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31799/discussion-between-furlan-and-cigano-morrison-mendez).

Answer (score 0):

Este erro ocorre devido a não existência de registros na tabela de Departamentos. Realize uma carga de dados nesta tabela e mude o campo IdDepartamento para uma combobox(Dropdownlist). Segue modelo:

HTML

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.IdDepartamento, 
            new SelectList(Model.Departamento, "--Escolha o departamento--" )
```

Comment: fiz umas alterações na pergunta, de uma olhada por favor