# Edit MVC com Foreign Key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Preciso dar uma melhorada em meu `editLivros`, a seguir vou explicar o meu projeto.

```
Autores
-------
IdAutor
Nome

Livros
--------
IdLivro
Nome
IdAutor
```

Estou cadastrando os Autores e Livros corretamente, quando eu for cadastrar o `Livro`, eu faço uma `ViewBag` para a lista dos autores :

`LivrosController` para pegar os Autores:

```
ViewBag.IdAutor = new SelectList(db.Autores, "IdAutor", "Nome");
```

`DropDown` dos Autores na `View Create` Livros:

```
@Html.DropDownList("IdAutor", ViewBag.IdAutor as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**Model Livros**

```
    public partial class Livros
{
    [Key]
    public int IdLivro { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public int IdAutor { get; set; }

    public virtual Autores Autores { get; set; }

}
```

**Model autores**

```
    public partial class Autores
{
    [Key]
    public int IdAutor { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

**Problema:**

O meu problema, é quando eu for editar o livro, automaticamente o `Visual Studio` pega o `Nome` do livro e o `IdAutor` do livro, porém, precisava gerar um `dropbox` com os autores, ai sim editar o autor do livro, passando o IdAutor do model `Autores`

Obrigado.

Comment: Ou seja, você quer poder salvar vários autores para um livro? Poste como está os Models Autores e Livros.

Comment: @Randrade na verdade amigo, queria deixar um dropdown com os autores na view edit, ai eu escolho o autor através do nome e ele pega o IdAutor, obrigado por responder

Comment: A mesma coisa [desta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/99056/20615)?

Comment: @Randrade coloquei na pergunta o Model de Autores e Livros

Comment: na verdade não, pq ele nao pega o IdAutor @Randrade

Comment: Não é só enviar um SelectList de novo na ViewBag e criar o DropDownList?

Comment: Orra, consegui @JedaiasRodrigues , tava embaixo do nariz kkk, me fala uma coisa, e para deixar o autor que está como default no dropdown?

Comment: vou editar uma resposta!

Comment: oK @JedaiasRodrigues obrigado desde já

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Edit do `LivrosController`:

```
ViewBag.listaAutores = db.Autores;
```

Na View do `Livros`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdAutor, ((IEnumerable<MVCCodeFirst.Models.Autores>)ViewBag.listaAutores).Select(option => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = option.Nome,
    Value = option.IdAutor.ToString(),
    Selected = (Model != null) && (Model.IdAutor == option.IdAutor)
}), "Selecione...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99307/edit-mvc-com-foreign-key#comment202000_99307... xD

Answer (score 5):

Bem, basta continuar fazendo como está. Enviando a `ViewBag` com o `SelectList` para a View Create Livros, mas nesse caso você já enviará um valor selecionado.

Ao criar um `SelectList`, é possível apontar como parâmetro o item a ser selecionado ([detalhes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd492553(v=vs.118).aspx)). Assim, ao chegar na sua View, seu `DropDownList` apresentará todos os itens disponíveis, mas deixará marcado o item indicado.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
ViewBag.IdAutor = new SelectList(db.Autores, "IdAutor", "Nome", Livro.IdAutor);
```

Existe também a possibilidade de fazer como na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99048/erro-ao-criar-dados-com-chave-estrangeira/99056#99056) que [@Randrade postou nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99307/edit-mvc-com-foreign-key/99315#comment202000_99307), o que muda apenas é o contexto.

Comment: assim não foi, eu fiz de outro jeito e foi

Comment: assim também funciona, mas como você fez?

Comment: olha a resposta que fiz, eu acho que pode ser mais fácil, n sei, oq acha?

Comment: Funciona e resolve o problema.